# Get NSDate to display a date from another timezone based on it's secondsFromGMT

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I am storing a record and this record has a date `pumpTimeNSDate` attached to it.

If the device that has created this record is placed on a different timezone from the device that is loading the record the device that is loading the record shows a different date from the date that is shown by the device that has created the record. I want them both to show the same date.

I understand that happens because the `NSDateFormatter()` adjusts the NSDate (which is just a reference in time) to the users current timezone taking in consideration it's distance from GMT.

**How do I get a device that is loading the record in a different timezone to show the same that is getting show on the device that has created the record?**

Note: originTimeOffsetObject stores how far from GMT was the device that has created the record.

```
    if let pumpTimeNSDate = objects[indexPath.row].objectForKey("pumpTimeNSDate") as? NSDate {

                let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "E dd, H:mm"

                if let originTimeOffsetObject = objects[indexPath.row].objectForKey("originTimeOffset") as? NSTimeInterval 
                {

                // not sure how to use originTimeOffsetObject

                }
                else
                {
                   // if timeoffset do not exist on DB
                   createdAt = formatter.stringFromDate(pumpTimeNSDate)
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create and set an NSTimeZone onto a NSDateFormatter. Since you know the offset, you can:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle   
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0) // Update to your value
dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()) // Display your date
```

Answer (score 1):

in difference timezone your date value still the same,but it's formated in current timezone.

So if You want to show time is the same every where, you can convert time to NSString with NSDateFormatter and timezone is your default fixed timezone. Or You can store time in NSString, in every where it will the same :)